# Stored Procedure returning duplicate results where as firing the sql it runs directly doesn't

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

We have got a stored procedure in SQL Server 2005 with a complicated bit of single select query. Recently in one environment, we noticed that for a small subset of the results returned by the stored proc, there were duplicate records. When we ran the sql query directly, we got the correct set of records without any duplicates. The stored procedure uses a lot of views and joins (inner join/left join). One theory I have is that somehow the stored procedure is using some cached execution plans as we have modified some views recently, but I don't have enough SQL expertise to be sure of that. Does any one have any idea?

Thanks for your help,
Ashish

Comment: You need to provide more info.  Is there any isolation level configuration in the proc?  Can you post some sample code?

Comment: I'd say you are barking up the wrong tree thinking that it is cached execution plans.  You should post as much of the SQL as you can inside your question and let people inspect that.

Comment: You sure you are using the exact same parameter types when you run the query directly? Are you declaring variables of the same type as the sp params an using those when running directly or just hardcoding values?

Comment: I've never seen what you're talking about. Often times the simplest answer is the right one. Did you data somehow change between the first execution and the second? Maybe you have an operation that adds records, your query executed and then the rows were deleted that were causing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Different results might be caused by different connection settings (e.g. ansi_nulls, arith_abort etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Run sp_recompile on the stored procedure to clear the procedure cache for that stored procedure.

To clear the entire procedure cache execute

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Here's an example of recompiling if you want to put it in a re-usable script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/****** Object:  Maintenance - StoredProcedure [Sample].[SampleSearch]    Script Date: 07/28/2011 14:15:15 ******/
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'Sample' AND ROUTINE_NAME = 'Sampleearch'))
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Marking procedure [Sample].[SampleSearch] for recompile'
    EXEC sp_recompile 'Sample.SampleSearch'
    PRINT 'Finished marking procedure [Sample].[SampleSearch] for recompile'
END

GO
```

However, if the query is returning different results, maybe turn on SQL tracing or debug the call from the code to ensure the same in and out parameters are being used in both cases.